# Assignment function as alternative to std::tie

Tags: c++, c++17, template

What do you think about this assignment "idiom"?

```
template <typename ...A>
constexpr auto assign(A& ...a) noexcept
{
  return [&](auto&& ...v)
//  noexcept(noexcept(((a = std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)), ...)))
    {
      ((a = std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)), ...);
    };
}
```

It seems a better alternative to me than the `std::tie()` idiom. Uncommenting the comment could cause a segfault in `gcc`.

Usage:

```
int a, b, c;
assign(a, b, c)(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Whether the syntax of your assignment idiom is better than std::tie is really questionable. Moreover, in c++17, structured bindings are much more neater. But +1 for use of lambda, I love lambdas in c++ they’re so op.

Comment: structured bindings for assignment? How?

Comment: One way: `auto [a, b, c] = std::array<int, 3>{1,2,3};`

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ fwiw, I believe OP's question is OK (if brief, and looking for "what do you think" feedback instead of code review). The "a,b,c" business is just sample usage, like a unit test. The 9-line snippet at the top of the question really _is_ valid C++ — the `...` in it are real C++17 syntax.

Comment: @user1095108, could you clarify the line about causing a segfault in GCC?  Is that a current development GCC, or an older release?  If the former, is there a bug report for it?  I find it's very rare to crash the compiler, largely because of good bug-reporting.

Comment: I reported the bug a long time ago and wasn't even the first person to do so. Supposedly, it's fixed now in the latest dev version, but not in 10.2 I currently use. Clang never had the bug.

Comment: Why is there a close vote to this question? It is perfectly reasonable

Comment: My close vote is because this is stub code without context.

Comment: What context could there possibly be? Assignment is universal.

Answer (score 3):

This "idiom" seems strictly more confusing than the `std::tie(a,b,c) = std::make_tuple(1,2,3)` idiom. (I mean, the latter is an idiom because multiple people use it and know it. Your thing doesn't count as an idiom yet because nobody uses or understands it.)

Your thing *does* save a lot of template instantiations — you don't have to instantiate `std::tuple` at all, for example. That's potentially nice for people who are doing lots of multiple assignments in header files and care about compile times. But who's doing lots of multiple assignments in header files??

Your thing *doesn't* fix the *most* important shortcoming of `std::tie`, which is that you can't use it to introduce a new variable. It's still fundamentally a `std::cin`-style API, where the caller is supposed to define all their variables with garbage values and then use this API to *mutate* them into the desired state.

```
// To mutate three variables:

int a, b, c;
assign(a, b, c)(1, 2, 3);
std::tie(a, b, c) = std::tuple{1, 2, 3};  // same deal, easier to read, harder to compile

// To define three new variables (ish):

auto [a, b, c] = std::tuple{1, 2, 3};
```

["C++17 structured binding that also includes an existing variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590449/c17-structured-binding-that-also-includes-an-existing-variable) gives the skeleton of an API that could be used to define and mutate different sets of variables at the same time:

```
// To define one new variable and mutate two others:

auto [a] = AndTie(_1, b, c) = std::tuple{1, 2, 3};
```

But again, I wouldn't describe this as an "idiom", because if you showed it to an ordinary C++ programmer who knew all the C++ idioms, they likely still wouldn't understand it at a glance.

---

Oh, and a code-style nit: I would prefer to see your fold-expression with spaces around the `,` operator, to emphasize that it's an operator and not a separator. Like this:

```
((a = std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)) , ...);
```

and in fact as long as we're saving on function template instantiations, let's do

```
((a = static_cast<decltype(v)>(v)) , ...);
```

The inner set of parentheses is redundant, I think, but I'm keeping them. (Precisely because I had to say "I think." I'm not even gonna go find out. They're a good idea.)

Comment: In a professional setting, I can imagine, that my "idiom" would be a big "no no" :) But in my personal projects, I really hate many lines of assignments. The "idiom" seems to have something going for it, one liner assignments, certain to confuse the uninitiated and maybe there's room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, it's useless.

Unlike `std::tie`, this `assign` function only works when both the list of variables and the list of values are loose.  It doesn't solve the major use case of `std::tie`, which is to have multiple return values from a function.

```
assign(a,b,c)(table_lookup(s,t)); // error
```

In fact, the only use case I know of for your `assign(a,b,c)(x,y,z)`, where anyone wouldn't just write

```
a=x;
b=y;
c=z;
```

is **when the output list aliases the input list**

```
assign(x,y)(y,x); // please swap, sir!
```

That line might really be written by someone more familiar with swap patterns in other languages than the C++ `std::swap` function.  Or when I can't use `std::swap` because the new values contain a more complicated expression:

```
// backward traversal of Fibonacci!!!
assign(a,b)(b-a,a);
```

But in this case with aliasing involved, your function doesn't even work as desired.

At least with

```
x=y;
y=x;
```

I know that the values will not be swapped.  With your function, the values still are not swapped, but I don't know that unless I look at the implementation.

If the assignments are taking too much vertical space, I can put multiple assignments on one line:

```
a=x; y=b; c=z;
```

It still is basic code understandable by even the least experienced programmer.  And that actually uses fewer characters than invoking your multiple-assignment helper.

Comment: You're not thinking broadly enough, imagine target variables in a set on the left side and source variables in a set on the right side. We allow the compiler make the connections between sources and targets in a declarative sense. c++ is becoming a declarative language. True, we need to make a slight change and copy the source variables to make it so and I can't change my question. Food-for-thought though.

Comment: @user1095108: I did imagine that, I included two examples in my answer, one for swap one for reverse Fibonacci.

Comment: the "idiom" came about after I needed some cheap (memory-wise) [containers](https://github.com/user1095108/xl) - just one example. I've debugged the resulting asm and I'm satisfied. I personally dislike having multiple assignments on one line like you showed and I like the work of the compiler, elimination of temporaries, ... If there are temporaries in play, the compiler knows best how to best optimize them. The traversal of an XOR list is a good example of a temp in play `assign(n, p)(n->link(p), n);`; p and n are swapped, n is reassigned and it's up to the compiler to make the best of it.

Comment: I already gave an example of a temp in play which breaks your solution because of aliasing.  Yes, it's possible to rewrite to make copies.  As far as "I dislike having multiple assignments on one line" I don't understand how "multiple updates on one line via two calls to helper functions" makes that any better.  The cognitive complexity is higher, first you have to decode what the helper is doing, then you still have to think about multiple variables changing.

Comment: @user1095108: And your example on github is insane because you use the identifier `assign` for two entirely different things, both being member functions of the same class!

Comment: one `assign` is private and the other is not, among other details. But anyway, it is food-for-thought. Other variations, perhaps more palatable, are possible. There will always be differences in taste and, as I wrote, I debugged and was satisfied with the resulting asm.

Comment: @user1095108: You are aware that private member functions affect overload resolution, correct?  Access checks are done after overload resolution, being `private` doesn't exclude it from the candidate set.

Comment: as I wrote, there are some additional details you might want to look at and, really, if you or someone else wrote the kind of container I needed and shared it with us, I might be one of its users right now, recommending it to others, but alas.